# Solution for $lim_{x\to 1}(\lceil x\rceil+\lceil x+1\rceil\cdot\lceil x+3\rceil)$

Tags: limits

Am I solving $lim_{x\to 1}(\lceil x\rceil+\lceil x+1\rceil\cdot\lceil x+3\rceil)$ correctly? Thank You!

$$
\begin{align*}
lim_{x\to 1}(\lceil x\rceil +\lceil x+1\rceil\cdot\lceil x+3\rceil)
&= 1 + (1+1)(1+3)\\
&= 1 + 2\cdot 4\\
&= 1 + 8\\
&= 9\\
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: I think what you are computing here is  $\lim_{x\rightarrow 1^{-}} \lceil x \rceil +\lceil  x+1\rceil*\lceil  x+3\rceil $,  what about   $\lim_{x\rightarrow 1^{+}} \lceil x \rceil +\lceil  x+1\rceil*\lceil  x+3\rceil $  i.e.  taking limit with  $x>1$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 1^{+}}\lceil{x}\rceil + \lceil{x+1}\rceil \times \lceil{x+3}\rceil = 2+3\times 5 = 17$$

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 1^{-}}\lceil{x}\rceil + \lceil{x+1}\rceil \times \lceil{x+3}\rceil = 1+2\times 4 = 9$$

So, the limit does not exists.

Comment: Hi sir, can you help me understand why am I calculating the value for x→1−? I always thought that I am doing it for +. I am sorry if this is a really basic question. Thank You!

Comment: In number line, $1$ can be approached from two ways - from the right side or from the left side. So, you have to calculate the limit value for both the cases. Try to go through the notion of $\epsilon - \delta$ definition of limit. Here is a wiki link of it- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/(%CE%B5,_%CE%B4)-definition_of_limit

Better to consult with I.A. Maron's 'Problems In Calculus Of One Variable' book.